# VirtualBox full screen mode, wrong aspect ratio

Tags: linux, windows-10, virtualbox, multiple-monitors, resolution

How can I avoid black stripes in the top and bottom of the screen when running Virtual Box full screen mode in an external monitor? See the screenshot below.

[image: Virtual Box full screen mode in the external monitor]

The external monitor has resolution 1920 x 1200 (aspect ratio 16:10). The internal screen has resolution 1920 x 1080 (aspect ratio 16:9).

I've tried to re-install Guest Additions, switch between normal and fullscreen modes, `VBoxManage setextradata "Windows 10" "CustomVideoMode1" "1920x1200x32"` etc. but nothing helps.

Host: Dell Precision 7510, Radeon HD 8890M, Debian Linux Stretch 64-bit, Xfce 4.12, VirtualBox 5.2.18

Guest: Windows 10 Pro 1809 64-bit, VirtualBox Guest Additions 5.2.18

Comment: Have you tried to change the resolution in guest OS?

Comment: There's no such resolution (1920 x 1200) available. See [the screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/Iaaeo3C.png). The maximum resolution seems to the native resolution of the internal screen.

Comment: How much video memory do you have assigned to that VM? Can you increase it?

Comment: Had 164 MB... Increased to 256 MB... → No effect.